# How to programmatically change contrast of a bitmap in android?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, contrast

I want to programmatically change the contrast of bitmap. Till now I have tried this.

```
private Bitmap adjustedContrast(Bitmap src, double value)
    {
        // image size
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        // create output bitmap
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        // color information
        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;
        // get contrast value
        double contrast = Math.pow((100 + value) / 100, 2);

        // scan through all pixels
        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                // get pixel color
                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                // apply filter contrast for every channel R, G, B
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                R = (int)(((((R / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
                if(R < 0) { R = 0; }
                else if(R > 255) { R = 255; }

                G = Color.green(pixel);
                G = (int)(((((G / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
                if(G < 0) { G = 0; }
                else if(G > 255) { G = 255; }

                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                B = (int)(((((B / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
                if(B < 0) { B = 0; }
                else if(B > 255) { B = 255; }

                // set new pixel color to output bitmap
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
            }
        }
        return bmOut;
    }
```

But this does not work as expected. Please help me in this or provide any other solution to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what doesn't work as expected? please elaborate more detailed what does work and what doesnt.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this. Your code didn't work because you create only a mutable bitmap and didn't copy the image of source bitmap to the mutable one if i'm not mistaken.

Hope It helps :)

```
private Bitmap adjustedContrast(Bitmap src, double value)
{
    // image size
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    // create output bitmap

    // create a mutable empty bitmap
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());

    // create a canvas so that we can draw the bmOut Bitmap from source bitmap
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    c.setBitmap(bmOut);

    // draw bitmap to bmOut from src bitmap so we can modify it
    c.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, new Paint(Color.BLACK));


    // color information
    int A, R, G, B;
    int pixel;
    // get contrast value
    double contrast = Math.pow((100 + value) / 100, 2);

    // scan through all pixels
    for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            // get pixel color
            pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            // apply filter contrast for every channel R, G, B
            R = Color.red(pixel);
            R = (int)(((((R / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            if(R < 0) { R = 0; }
            else if(R > 255) { R = 255; }

            G = Color.green(pixel);
            G = (int)(((((G / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            if(G < 0) { G = 0; }
            else if(G > 255) { G = 255; }

            B = Color.blue(pixel);
            B = (int)(((((B / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            if(B < 0) { B = 0; }
            else if(B > 255) { B = 255; }

            // set new pixel color to output bitmap
            bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }
    return bmOut;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think we need a `Canvas` here -- we're writing to the bitmap `bmOut` directly.

Comment: what is max and min values can update your answer with this values

Answer (score 66):

Here is complete method:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param bmp input bitmap
 * @param contrast 0..10 1 is default
 * @param brightness -255..255 0 is default
 * @return new bitmap
 */
public static Bitmap changeBitmapContrastBrightness(Bitmap bmp, float contrast, float brightness)
{
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                0, 0, 0, 1, 0
            });

    Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ret);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This's the fastest solution I found so far. Probably only a renderscript-based one would be faster...

Comment: Awesome, this method processes my image in about a second, above method took about 20 seconds.

Comment: what is the max & min value of contrast & brightness. I use -255 t0 255 for brightness & -100 to 100 for contrast, but i get wrong result.
I also try to use value 0 for contrast while some value for brightness i get a black image.Please help me. I got this is the fastest method, but it give me wrong result, definitely i do something wrong, it would be nice if any one correct me.

Comment: Just a improvement to the code due to the constant break on the bmp.getConfig...

Bitmap.Config config = src.getConfig();
        if (config == null) {
            config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), config);

Comment: This will create OutOfMemmory if we are changing the brightness through silder

Answer (score 8):

We can use `seek bar` to adjust contrast.

[image]

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    SeekBar seekbar;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);

        seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(changeBitmapContrastBrightness(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lhota), (float) progress / 100f, 1));
                textView.setText("Contrast: "+(float) progress / 100f);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        });

        seekbar.setMax(200);
        seekbar.setProgress(100);
    }

    public static Bitmap changeBitmapContrastBrightness(Bitmap bmp, float contrast, float brightness) {
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
                {
                        contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0
                });

        Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ret);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.java:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

> Assumption - ImageView is used to display the bitmap

I did a more enhancement in the Ruslan's answer

Instead of replacing **bitmap** every time (which makes it slow if you are using seek bar) we can work on the **Color Filter** of the ImageView.

```
float contrast;
float brightness = 0;
ImageView imageView;

// SeekBar ranges from 0 to 90
// contrast ranges from 1 to 10  
mSeekBarContrast.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            contrast = (float) (i + 10) / 10;
            // Changing the contrast of the bitmap
            imageView.setColorFilter(getContrastBrightnessFilter(contrast,brightness));
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
});

ColorMatrixColorFilter getContrastBrightnessFilter(float contrast, float brightness) {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                    0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                    0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
            });
    return new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
}
```

P.S - Brightness can also be changed along with contrast using this method

Comment: This is best method to make contrast and brightness to the image. It works faster then other tools. Thank you so much

Comment: now, it is working very fine. If we seek back from 50 then the image gets dark and if we seek more from 50 then image gets bright.

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2023: [Since Renderscript is deprecated since Android 12](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate), this solution is not recommended anymore.**

---

Here is a Renderscript implementation ([from the Gradle Example Projects](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system))

ip.rsh

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(your.app.package)
```

contrast.rs

```
#include "ip.rsh"

static float brightM = 0.f;
static float brightC = 0.f;

void setBright(float v) {
    brightM = pow(2.f, v / 100.f);
    brightC = 127.f - brightM * 127.f;
}

void contrast(const uchar4 *in, uchar4 *out)
{
#if 0
    out->r = rsClamp((int)(brightM * in->r + brightC), 0, 255);
    out->g = rsClamp((int)(brightM * in->g + brightC), 0, 255);
    out->b = rsClamp((int)(brightM * in->b + brightC), 0, 255);
#else
    float3 v = convert_float3(in->rgb) * brightM + brightC;
    out->rgb = convert_uchar3(clamp(v, 0.f, 255.f));
#endif
}
```

Java

```
private Bitmap changeBrightness(Bitmap original RenderScript rs) {
    Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, original);
    final Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
    ScriptC_contrast mScript = new ScriptC_contrast(rs);
    mScript.invoke_setBright(50.f);
    mScript.forEach_contrast(input, output);
    output.copyTo(original);
    return original;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more completed example?

Comment: the sample is pretty complete, for integrating it see the link, bottom of the page with full projects

Comment: anyway can you post direct link to full project? :) I found only one link and it's unavailable

Comment: They seem to have removed the link to the projects, just search how to create an app with renderscript, the rest should be clear

Comment: RenderScript APIs are deprecated starting in Android 12

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and ended up using the `Color Matrix` that Ruslan Yanchyshyn describes. I needed to automatically adjust brightness depending on the image, so I used BoofCV to create a histogram from a scaled version of the image - It took way to long to process the whole image. Then I analyzed the histogram - looked at what was the darkest and brightest colors and then created a color matrix which transforms the colors so the darkest colors are 0 and the brightest colors are 255. In this way the new image uses the whole spectrum from dark/black to light/white now.

Ended up writing a small post on how I did it on our company blog here if anyone are interested. http://appdictive.dk/blog/projects/2016/07/26/levels_with_color_matrix/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this one:

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/image-processing-contrast-image-on-the-fly/

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this. But this code works with canvas only and I cannot retrieve the changed image from canvas. So is there any other way for it.

Comment: I edited the link above. I hope that will be more helpful in your case. :)

Comment: It is the same code that I gave above. It always make my image black and white and does not make it back to its original colors. Please provide any other.

Answer (score 1):

http://android.okhelp.cz/bitmap-set-contrast-and-brightness-android/

have a look at this ,this might solve your problem