# How to change screen contrast of my android device?

Tags: android, contrast, android-settings

Servus!

I am coding a demo for a prototype with a build in Z1 android phone watch. Problem is that the default contrast setting for its display is pretty bad. Depending on my brightness setting I can choose between black looks like grey or white looks like grey.
So I went out and found an app called "Screen Adjuster" to change the screen contrast. But the thing is that this only let me lower the contract, but I need to raise it to get rid of the grey-color-problem.

Now I looked how to change the screen-settings on my own and did that at least for brightness. But now I got stuck searching for a way to get to some sort of contrast setting handle. I wonder if the app did that by some sort of filter overlay or something?? At least this would explain why its not possible to raise the contrast...

I need ideas!

edit: The device runs Android 2.2.1 and is already rooted.

Comment: Take a look this answer . I think it will help you 
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/12892076/1214847][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12892076/1214847

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that. But the contrast of the picture material isn't the problem, its the screen itself that needs to be adjusted.

Comment: It's not looks like as a programming question.

Comment: @Drivers Well, as I said I changed brightness programmaticly, am searching for a way to do that with contrast now and I did not ask for shell commands... But as you implicitly mention that: Maybe android has something like xrandr or xcalib that is accessible via adbshell...